# Run multiple asgi apps in same thread with uvicorn

Tags: python, python-asyncio, asgi, uvicorn

I want to run a starlette and django app in the same thread.

(Having them in same thread allows fast thread-local communication between them).

Considering that asgi apps are just coroutines, I thought this should be theoretically possible with `asyncio.gather()`.

---

I came up with a little hack to make this work, but it has some limitations.

```py
from uvicorn import Server, Config

configs = [Config(app1, uds='app1.sock'), Config(app2, uds='app2.sock')]
coros = [Server(c).serve() for c in configs]

await asyncio.gather(*coros)
```

---

1. Doesn't support `reload` and `workers` options.
2. Ctrl+C only works for one app.

```
INFO:     Started server process [86066]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Started server process [86066]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on unix socket app1.sock (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on unix socket app2.sock (Press CTRL+C to quit)
^CINFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Finished server process [86066]
^C^C^C^C^C
```

What's a better way to do this?

Comment: this seems ok to me, what you don't like about it, better in what way ? came here from  https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/pull/510/ which would handle running multiple uvicorns in multiple threads, so it's different from what you're asking if I got it correctly @dev-aggarwal

Comment: Yeah, I think I was looking somewhere I wasn't supposed to :D. Sorry for bugging you!

Answer (score 8):

Update - If you have a separation of paths between 2 apps, you can use this to skip starlette's middleware:

```py
from mydjangoapp.asgi import application as django_app

ws_app = Starlette(...)

async def app(scope, receive, send):
    path = scope.get("path")
    chosen = ws_app
    if not (path is None or path.startswith("/ws")):
        chosen = django_app
    return await chosen(scope, receive, send)
```

---

Silly me! Starlette supports mounting arbitrary ASGI apps, which means you can just do the following and use any ol' ASGI server from the command line.

```py
from mydjangoapp.asgi import application as django_app

app = Starlette(...)

app.mount('/', django_app)
```